# How do I add dynamic content to a div generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-content

Basically I am validating a form, I am collecting the error messages and I am appending them to a div generated dynamiclly. Now I am unable to append these message to this div .here is what I had done

```
//generates a div onclick of submit button
$("body").append("<div class='overlay'><div class='errorContainer'>.html(errorMsg)</div><div>`<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='cross'>X</a><div></div>");
```

`.html(errorMsg)`  this causes error/is incorrect

```
function closeErrorBox() {
            var errorMsg = "";
                var ferrorMsg =  "Please say your first name" + "<br>";
                var aerrorMsg = "Please type address" + "<br>";
                var eerrorMsg = "Please type a valid email Address" + "<br>"
                if($("#name").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += ferrorMsg;
                }
                if($("#address").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += aerrorMsg;
                }
                if($("#email").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += eerrorMsg;
                }

                $(".errorContainer").html(errorMsg);


                $(".overlay").remove();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.errorContainer` div is inside the `.overlay` div. When you remove overlay in the end of your function, errorContainer is removed too. Other than that, it seems the `.html(errorMsg)`
 is working fine (if it still causing error, please specify what's going wrong).

Re-reading your question, I couldn't understand you program's flow: are you adding that div when the error is already known, and closing it when you click the "X"? If thats the case, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
var errorMsg = "";
var ferrorMsg =  "Please say your first name" + "<br>";
var aerrorMsg = "Please type address" + "<br>";
var eerrorMsg = "Please type a valid email Address" + "<br>"
if($("#name").val() == "") {
    errorMsg += ferrorMsg;
}
if($("#address").val() == "") {
    errorMsg += aerrorMsg;
}
if($("#email").val() == "") {
    errorMsg += eerrorMsg;
}

// Adapting Diego's answer:
$("<div class='overlay'><div class='errorContainer'></div><div><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='cross'>X</a><div></div>")
    .appendTo($("body"))
    .find(".errorContainer")
        .html(errorMsg)
        .end()
    .find(".cross")
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".overlay").remove();
        });
```

Comment: this looks very promising, but i just had a question, everytime i click on submit button, it adds an overlay. will you code remove that problem as well. thanks

Comment: No, it won't. If you want only one overlay, I'd suggest not creating it dynamically, but statically (put it right in your html). Have it start hidden (`style="display:none"`), show it when needed in your submit (`$(".overlay").show()`) and hide it in the `.cross`'s click (`$(".overlay").hide()`). This way you avoid appending/removing it unnecessarily.

Comment: it doesn't work, firebug says  errorMsg is not defined in the line  .html(errorMsg)

Comment: That's probably some issue with the rest of your code. You can see a working example of my proposed solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/h5msy/). If you're still having problems, please update your question with more info.

Comment: No doubt I changes my code some bit but here is what I have now and it doesn't woek  http://jsfiddle.net/G9rxp/4/, I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: 1. There are `<script>` tags inside your javascript! It doesn't even compile... thanks for creating a fiddle, but please check your code in a debugger before posting it here. (you mentioned you use Firebug, unfortunatly it doesn't warn you of compile errors like Chrome does. I hate that too...) 2. After this correction, your code is fine; you just need to remember to move your error checking code to inside the submit callback, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/G9rxp/5/). I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, I really appreciate your help on this. +1 added and accepted. just a question, is this a good way to validate form. your suggestions on this or is there a better solution that you may have

Comment: From my experience, this is a good way, it's the same I use in my forms. There is a plugin, [jquery-validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), that looks promising, but I haven't tried it myself, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
//generates a div onclick of submit button
$("body").append("<div class='overlay'><div class='errorContainer'></div><div><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='cross'>X</a><div></div>").find(".errorContainer").html(errorMsg);
```

Comment: If there are more than one `.overlay`, all the `.errorContainer`s in the page will receive the same error message. I'd suggest using `appendTo` on the newly created div, instead of `append` on the body (so `find` will be restricted to that div).

Comment: thanks but everytime I click on submit button, the overlay is added. how do i avoid it.I mean add overlay only once